# How to disable webview zoom out?

Tags: android

I am loading javascript file in webview but If I double click a web view, it zooms out. Is there any way to disable that?

Thanks
Monali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
WebView browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webkit);
WebSettings mWebSettings = browser.getSettings();
mWebSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
```

in above code `mWebSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);` will do your task.

Reference : [setBuiltInZoomControls(boolean enabled)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setBuiltInZoomControls%28boolean%29)

Answer (score 0):

WebSetting class has method setSupportZoom(boolean) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setSupportZoom(boolean)